# Резко перестала работать программа. В чём дело?

Tags: python

Некоторое время назад программа работала - выводила уравнения и слова. Сейчас же она не запускается

```
def main():
    argument1 = [[1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 0]]
    argument2 = [[0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1]]
    template = [argument1, argument2]

    n = 1
    for data in template:
        print_data(data)


def print_data(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            print_images_foreach_delta(data, i, j)


def print_images_foreach_delta(data, i, j):
    size = len(data[0])
    for delta in range(1, size - (i + j)):
        for image_index in range(len(data)):
            print_image(data, image_index, i, j, delta)


def print_image(data, image_index, i, j, delta):
    print('Изображение номер - ', image_index + 1, sep="")
    for func in range(len(data)):
        print(f'{int(func == image_index)} = R{func + 1} = {data[image_index][i]} * A1({func + 1}) + {data[image_index][i + j + delta]} * A2({func + 1})')


if name == "main":
    main()
```

Comment: Что значит "не запускается"? Что происходит вместо запуска?

Comment: Я получаю ошибку: 
line 32, in <module>
    if name == "main":
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: Вроде кажется очевидным, он жалуется на то, что у программы нет того самого name, но я её ранее не видоизменял

Comment: `if name == "main":` --> `if __name__ == "main":`

Comment: Я об этом тоже думал. Программа больше не выдаёт ошибки, но она всё равно не показывает решение уравнений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Благодарю! Всё наконец заработало как и должно было быть! На этом думаю я могу закрыть этот вопрос. 
Всем участникам консилиума - спасибо и моя благодарность